# Verb phrase and other elements

Tags: grammar

For this sentence...

```
Are you a collector of art?
```

Can someone tell me the different parts of it please?

I think...

`Are` is the verb.

`you` is the noun.

What is `a collector` in the sentence?

What part is the verb phrase?

What part is the predicate?

What part is the subject?

Comment: Would you care to explain why you downmarked my answer.

Comment: I didn't downmark it.  Not sure who did or why?  My question was downmarked as well.  I actually upvoted your answer!

Comment: Oh, OK then. Thank you. Btw, would things be clearer if I drew a tree diagram of your sentence?

Comment: Sure that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Tree Diagram of Sentence]

Here's a tree diagram of your sentence.

Note that the prenucleus verb "are" is co-indexed to gap in the nucleus clause with the *i* notation.

At each node there are two labels: the first is a function label, the second a category label.
Key: D = determinative, Det = determiner, Pred,comp = predicative complement

Answer (score -1):

> *Are you a collector of art?*

"A collector of art" is a noun phrase functioning as subjective predicative complement of the verb "are". It's called subjective because it relates to the subject, the noun phrase "you". Internally, the noun phrase has "a" as determiner, and "collector" as head, which has the preposition phrase "of art" functioning as its complement.

The predicate consists of the verb phrase "__ a collector of art", where the gap notation '___' represents the prenuclear predicator "are". It's a prenucleus because it's external to the nucleus clause "you __ a collector of art".